# How to play on the same Minecraft bedrock account across devices?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

What I mean by that is, for example, I have a world that I've put onto a server on Windows 10 Bedrock. I've been able to connect to it on my phone while logged into the same Xbox Live account, but it treats it as two different accounts. I'd like to be able to log onto the server through the same XBL, whether on iOS or Windows 10, and continue my progress. Is this possible somehow and I'm just missing it?

Edit: I would prefer to be able to do it through the server software, not through the Realms.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this without issue. Are you using Bedrock Dedicated Server or are you idling the Win10 version as a LAN game? If the latter, then yes, you'll be two separate accounts. You should not have this problem, however, if you are running your world via a Bedrock Dedicated server and not connecting simultaneously with the same account.

One thing to note...if you move a local save file to a dedicated bedrock server, your account goes from being a "local" player to a "remote" player which is a completely separate inventory. An easy work-around for this is to throw everything in your inventory into a chest before migrating a local save to a BDS server.